# Kann sich ein Schwerpunkt mit etwas befassen?

Tags: word-usage

Ich würde einfach gerne wissen, wie ich argumentieren kann, warum der folgende Satz falsch/richtig ist? Muss ich mich dort von der grammatikalischen lösen?

> Der Schwerpunkt befasst sich mit …

Ein Schwerpunkt kann sich doch mit nichts befassen? Oder etwa doch?

Comment: Das hat nichts mit Deutsch zu tun, denn ein Schwerpunkt - in welcher Sprache auch immer - kann sich nicht mit etwas befassen. Es ist eher ein Kategorienfehler und gehört in den Bereich der Philosophie.

Comment: Die Formulierung ist im akademischen Bereich recht verbreitet, z.B. "Der Schwerpunkt Islamwissenschaft befasst sich mit der islamischen Religion und der Geschichte der von ihr geprägten Gesellschaften". Könnte diese Formulierung aus dem Englischen kommen?

Comment: "Der Schwerpunkt befasst sich mit ..." wäre im Englischen so was wie "The focus deals with ...". Für mich klingt das im Englischen so schief wie im Deutschen, ich denke man sagt einfach "The focus is on ..."

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Der Schwerpunkt meines Hirns befasst sich mit Kategorientheorie (Eine Monade ist ein Monoid in der Kategorie der Endofunktoren).

Comment: @userunknown Der Schwerpunkt deines Hirns ist wahrscheinlich ziemlich in der Mitte. Außer du nickst gerade.

Comment: Schreibe bitte den ganzen Satz hin. Je nach Kontext wäre es durchaus möglich, wenn mit »Schwerpunkt« nämlich etwas anderes als der physikalische Massenmittelpunkt. Das Wort wird nämlich sehr oft im übertragenen Sinn verwendet.

Comment: @tofro: Der Schwerpunkt eines Objekts, das eine starre Kapsel ausfüllt, bleibt auch beim Nicken dort wo er immer ist: ziemlich in der Mitte.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Antwort ist: jein.

Es kommt nämlich auf den Kontext an bzw. darauf, wie das Wort *Schwerpunkt* verwendet wird.

Setzt man es im direkten Sinne ein:

> Der Schwerpunkt seiner Forschung liegt auf der Verbindung von Erwachsenenpädagogik und Gesellschaftskritik

dann muss man auch etwas wie *liegen* als Verb verwenden. "Der Schwerpunkt befasst sich..." geht hier nicht, da das Bild gebrochen würde. Der Schwerpunkt ist immer noch ein Punkt, und ein Punkt kann aufgrund seiner Natur liegen, sich befinden, er kann sich vielleicht auch von A nach B bewegen oder ziellos mäandern, aber er kann sich nicht "befassen", jedenfalls nicht nach den etablierten Gewohnheiten des Sprechens und den etablierten Regeln guten Stils beim Schreiben.

Anders dagegen wenn *Schwerpunkt* hier als Platzhalter eingesetzt wird, d.h. wenn das Wort für etwas anderes steht. Kommentatorin Iris hat einen solchen Fall aufgespürt:

> Der Schwerpunkt Islamwissenschaft befasst sich mit der Erforschung von...

Das geht, wenn *Schwerpunkt* hier für eine Untereinheit einer Universität o.ä. steht, etwa wie *Fachbereich*, ein Institut, eine temporäres Cluster von Lehrstühlen oder was auch immer. In diesem Fall *befasst* sich ja das Institut oder es *befassen* sich seine Mitarbeiter. Beides ist fürs allgemeine deutsche Sprachempfinden eine zulässige Kollokation.

Comment: Also steht *der Schwerpunkt* im letzteren Fall für *die Schwerpunktgruppe*. Sehe ich auch so.

Answer (score 1):

Befassen kann sich der Schwerpunkt nicht, aber er kann auf einem Thema, einem Bereich oder ähnlichem liegen. Oder man kann sich schwerpunktmäßig - im Sinne von konzentriert - mit etwas befassen.